# If $\lim x_n=x$ and $x>0$, prove that there exists a natural number $M$ such that $x_n>0$ for all $n \geq M$

Tags: real-analysis

If $\lim x_n=x$ and $x>0$, prove that there exists a natural number $M$ such that $x_n>0$ for all $n \geq M$

I have tried to write down the definition of $\lim x_n=x$ which is 
$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N} \text{ st }\forall n\geq N,|x_n-x|<\epsilon$$

But I have no idea how to relate it to the consequent.

Comment: What happens if there is no such $M$? Then you will have infinitely-many points that are $\leq 0$. Can $x>0$ then be the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you said, 
$$\lim x_n=x \iff
\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N} \text{ s.t. }\forall n\geq N,|x_n-x|<\epsilon.$$
So, for example, with $\epsilon = \frac{x}{2}$ you have :
$$ \exists M\in\mathbb{N} \text{ s.t. }\forall n\geq N, 0<\frac{x} {2}<x_n<\frac{3x}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon = \frac{x}{2}$.

Pick $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n \geq N$, we have

$$ |x_n - x| < \epsilon $$
$$ x - x_n \leq |x_n - x| < \epsilon = \frac{x}{2} $$
$$ x_n > x - \frac{x}{2} = \frac{x}{2} > 0$$